Preferences don't saving in unity
When I select Visual Studio Code in External Tools, Unity does not save the settings. And after restarting Unity, the external script editor is installed by opening it by file extension. If Visual Studio Code is not installed in an external script editor, there are no tooltips in VS Code.
all of packeges im using: https://i.sstatic.net/DaeyzaY4.png

Do you have the according unity package installed?

which one? If "VS Code editor" or "VS editor" yeah.

You should install "Visual Studio Code Editor" package in Unity and “Unity for Visual Studio Code” extension in Visual Studo Code.

"VS code editor"  pacage in unity is instailed. "Unity" for visual studio code is instailed too.

What do you mean by "And after restarting Unity, the external script editor is installed by opening it by file extension. If Visual Studio Code is not installed in an external script editor, there are no tooltips in VS Code."

That's literally what it means. In VS Code, for example, there are no tooltips associated with Raycast, Rigidbody and Vector3 without VS code set in preferences>external tools.

You can set them manually via https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html. Either with Unity's API or via regedit. (I had the same problem with Unity LTS before Unity 6)
